# Converting multiple Postscript images into an animated gif

Tags: animation, animated-gif, postscript

I have several postscript images of the form "filename_0001.ps", "filename_0002.ps", etc. I would like to create an animated gif with each of the files as a frame in the animation, but I do not know how I would go about doing that. I have over 500 files that I would like to include in a single gif and would like to avoid creating the animated gif by hand.

I googled around for a bit and found [this](http://abel.math.harvard.edu/computing/ps/). At the very bottom it seems to suggest that there is a one line command that can be used to make the gif, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it in my case.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used `ghostscript` and ImageMagick's `convert` to do this. I used these commands

```
gs -sDEVICE=png48 -g500x500 -o bezan%03d.png bezanim.ps
convert bezan*.png bezan.gif
```

to produce this animation for [this Codegolf.Stackexchange challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/21178/animated-drawing-of-a-bezier-curve/21507#21507), where the frames were separate pages of a single postscript program.

[image: Animated Bezier Curve]

You can probably do it with the single command

```
convert filename_*.ps anim.gif
```

and `convert` will shell-out to `ghostscript` as needed. But for my case, I wanted to specify the arguments to ghostscript directly.

Comment: Howcome you never bother to antialias your images :P Would be pretty simple.

Comment: @joojaa I actually don't know how to do that. Can you explain a little, or do you think I should make a new question, like "How to antialias images rendered from postscript?"?

Comment: just render at 2-3 the res per side and sample down . Something like imagemagic would be trivial to use for this purpose.

Comment: Heres what it could look like: http://i.imgur.com/Jtk2Yrr.gif and i used this cmdline: **convert bezan*.png -set option:filter:lobes 8 -resize 25% result.png** then made those to a gifanim. The kind of raster color you use is slightly unoptimal but didn't change the input all that much (made lines a bit wider and image bigger that's all)